# how to specify specific object path in a json

Tags: java, json, scala, json4s

Im using json4s to parse a json to my scala case class object, and the first one worked great:

```
case class Person(Id: String, name: String)

val personJSON = """[ {"Id": "1","name": "john"},
                      {"Id": "2","name": "george"},
                      {"Id": "3","name": "tom"},
                      {"Id": "4","name": "tammy"},
                      {"Id": "5","name": "melanie"}  ]""".stripMargin

val listOfPersonAsObjects = JsonMethods.parse(personJSON).extract[List[Person]]
```

works perfect, no problem.

but now the json is one that has object inside of it:

```
case class Animal(name: String, age: String)

val animalsJSON = """{ "animals":[ {"name": "giraffe","age": "12"},
                       {"name": "lion","age": "4"},
                       {"name": "snake","age": "5"},
                       {"name": "tiger","age": "3"},
                       {"name": "elephant","age": "7"}] }""".stripMargin
```

so now I need to parse the "animals:" object inside the json...

what I thought is something like this:

```
val listOfAnimalsAsObjects = JsonMethods.parse(animalsJSON[0]).extract[List[Animal]]
```

but its not working...how can I specify that I want "animals:" object inside the json?

i can not change the json, its exactly how im getting it

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The JSON that isn't working for you is not a list. It is an object that contains a list. Therefore, your object needs to match that structure.

Something like this:

```
class AnimalListContainer
{
    List<Animal> Animals;
    public AnimalListContainer()
    {
        Animals = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

And then later when you try to parse:

```
val animalListContainer = JsonMethods.parse(animalsJSON[0]).extract[AnimalListContainer]
```

(Untested code  - sorry for any syntax errors).

Comment: i can not change the json, its exactly how im getting it @Justin Conroy

Comment: @jackmiao Updated answer to handle non-changing JSON.